# Having issues with pipe, fork, dup2

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I am using pipes, fork , dup2 to implement “ls | more” or “ls | sort” etc. 
I am just not able to understand the issue here.
When I run my program, I get this error:

```
./a.out  
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)
```

Why am I getting "less" ??

What is wrong with this code ? If I change “more” to “ls” again, it works fine. I mean, its like doing ls | ls.

```
#define STDIN 0
#define STDOUT 1

int main()
{
   int fd[2];
   int pid;
   char *lschar[20]={"ls",NULL};
   char *morechar[20]={"more",NULL};
   pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0) {
   /* child */
     int cpid;
     cpid = fork();
     if(cpid == 0) {
       //printf("\n in ls \n");
       pipe(fd);
       dup2(fd[1], STDOUT);
       close(fd[0]);
       close (fd[1]);
       execvp("ls",lschar);
     } else if(cpid>0) {
       waitpid(cpid, NULL,0);
       dup2(fd[0],STDIN);
       close(fd[0]);
       close(fd[1]);
       execvp("more", morechar);
     }
   } else if (pid > 0) {
     /* Parent */
     waitpid(pid, NULL,0);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: "Why am I getting 'less'": because the `more` command is implemented by the `less` command on your machine.

Comment: Oh ok. But why the error ? Any idea ? I am not seeing any issue with the program. Tried gdb also, didn't succeed.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but you're getting the error because you're invoking `more`/`less` without any arguments. You can run `ls` without any arguments, but not `less`. Try it from the command line; it'll give you the same error.

Comment: I had to implement a UNIX shell. I was implementing this piece of code for commands like "ls | sort" or "ls | sort" etc. I am thinking the ls is not getting executed first so more is not getting any input.

Comment: Shouldn't the `pipe()` call happen before the second `fork()` for it to be available in both the parent and child process? Or at least outside the `if(cpid == 0) { ... }` block?

Comment: Ah. Never noticed that `less` checks its input and allows you not to give a file name in some cases. So in theory if you had the pipe setup correctly, it wouldn't give an error. I wasn't going to comment on the rest of the code because I don't really have time to check it all. But you should look for some example code using `fork()` and `pipe()`. You're executing `pipe()` after `fork()` which is backwards but you need other changes as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your main problem lies in your placement of the `pipe()` call. You must call it *before* you `fork()`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define STDIN 0
#define STDOUT 1

int main()
{
  int fd[2];
  int pid;
  char *lschar[20]={"ls",NULL};
  char *morechar[20]={"more", NULL};
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    /* child */
    int cpid;
    pipe(fd);
    cpid = fork();
    if(cpid == 0) {
      //printf("\n in ls \n");
      dup2(fd[1], STDOUT);
      close(fd[0]);
      close (fd[1]);
      execvp("ls",lschar);
    } else if(cpid>0) {
      dup2(fd[0],STDIN);
      close(fd[0]);
      close(fd[1]);
      execvp("more", morechar);
    }
  } else if (pid > 0) {
    /* Parent */
    waitpid(pid, NULL,0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, the more process doesn't have the correct file descriptors. Further, the waitpid() in your more process is problematic and unnecessary (more will wait for input on its own). If ls had a particularly long output the pipe could get full causing ls to block on its writes. The result is a deadlock and it waits forever. Hence, I've also removed the offending `waitpid()` call.

Also, if you make a good practice of checking the return values of functions like `pipe()` and `dup2()` this error would have been much easier to find -- you would have seen that your `dup2()` was failing.

Comment: As an aside, the error message you saw was most likely `more` calling `isatty(0)` to check if `stdin` is a tty. That's how it can differentiate between you just running it with no args and you actually piping something into it. Another handy POSIX call to stick in your pocket ;).