# Passing a pipe address through argv

Tags: c, pipe, exec, argv

I'm trying to set up a program where one process establishes a pipe, which is then passed to its children for either reading or writing. I tried to do it using the argv parameter to communicate the address of the pipe for the children to use, but I'm doing it wrong and keep getting a segmentation fault when I try to run it

Parent:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv [ ]){
int temp,B,C,D,num; char *arg[1]={0};

int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
B=1;
C=1;
D=1;
sprintf(arg[0], "%d", fd);

B=fork();
if (B==0){execv("PipeW1", arg);}

C=fork();
if (C==0){execv("PipeW2", arg);}

D=fork();
if (D==0){execv("PipeR", arg);}
```

Children

```
void main(int argc, char *argv [ ]){
int *fd = atoi(argv[0]);
//pipe(fd);
close(fd[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, `argv[0]` will be name of your executable, first "real" argument will be in `argv[1]`. It might be a good idea to check if you have appropriate number of arguments before accessing them in `argv` array. 
Another thing is that in your child process you should initialize `fd` as int not pointer to int.
 Third problem might be that in `close(fd[1])` you are treating fd as array when in fact it is a scalar integer value.
 So much for likely problems in you child proccess...

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your segfault, you declared arg like this:

```
char *arg[1]={0};
```

That means that arg[0] is a null pointer, so you get a segfault when you sprintf(arg[0],...) .

Try allocating some memory for it first.  Since you're printing a file descriptor which is a small integer, you don't need much, maybe 2 bytes for the number plus another for the nul terminator on the string.  Then use snprintf() instead of sprintf() to ensure you don't go past that if for some reason you've got a three digit number for your file descriptor:

```
arg[0] = malloc(3);
snprintf(arg[0], 3, "%d", fd);
```

And then don't forget to `free(arg[0]);` when you're all done with it.

Edit:

As for the other part of your question, you're actually probably better off not messing around with passing the file descriptors as strings, and just use dup2(2) to map the pipe descriptors to stdin/stdout in the child, as shown in this other related question:

[Having issues with pipe, fork, dup2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041796/having-issues-with-pipe-fork-dup2)